# Are GetStream React components providing localization?

Tags: getstream-io

We are including both **chat** and **activity feed** React components on a website, which is displayed in multiple languages.

There are some texts like input placeholders or buttons with english default values, and I've seen that some of these texts are customizable with props.
For instance, the component for the new post form has a *Header* prop (default is a "New Post" Title, see documentation below) that lets me change it for something else.

https://getstream.github.io/react-activity-feed/#statusupdateform

However I'm not sure texts for all components and sub-components are covered by this technique and, even if it is, it seems painful to change every single text values for each component, with localized texts retrieved from backend...

I was wondering if I've missed something in the documentation that would provide already-fully-working localization, or at least some support for it.

If not, has someone an idea of what would be the best way to achieve localization ?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently implementing this at Stream Chat, starting with the react-native SDK and then we'll port it to the react SDK afterward. Then we'll be implementing it on Stream Feeds a bit further down the line. The best way to stay informed is to subscribe to the Github repo for the SDK and keep an eye on updates.

Of course, our SDK's are open source so you're welcome to open a PR for our developers to review!

Stephen

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
So the best way for the moment would be to overload the components sources I guess